# Echo text in a certain color in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am about to write a shell script. I would like to be able to visually distinguish some of its output text as a warning, by setting its color to yellow.

How is this done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From "[ShellHacks: Bash Colors](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-colors/)":

```
echo -e "\033[33mThis is yellow\033[0m"
```

or

```
echo -e "\e[33mThis is yellow\e[0m"
```

`\033` or `\e` as an [Escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) starts the escape sequence, which in this case contains the controls to change colors.

Comment: Thanks for the update @slhck, it provided a more complete answer ;)

Comment: The link leads to a page which is quite unusable (blocked by adds...)